# What are the best ways to reference branches of a JSON tree structure?

Tags: javascript, json, tree

So I've got a JSON file that gets parsed into an object in Javascript. I know what you're thinking: lucky guy. The JSON is essentially a flow diagram in a big tree form. Here's tiny a sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
tree = {
    "options": [
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "target",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "link": "...?",
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

So in this example, I'll be deep in the second branch (where it says `"link"`) and I'll want to be able to jump to the branch that contains `"name": "target"`. This is JSON remember so it'll need to be a string (unless there's a native for linking?! is there?) but I don't know how best to format that.

As I see it, I've got at least a couple of options.

1. I could search. If `name` was unique, I could scale the tree looking for elements until I found it. I've never done with with Javascript before but I expect it to be slow.
2. I could use a navigation path like `options:1:options:1` that describes each key for the path. Again, I've never done this but, assuming there are no errors, it would be a lot faster. How would you implement it?

Are there any other options available to me? What seems best? Is there a way to unpack this when JSON decoding, or is that a recipe for an infinite loop?

Comment: It's not clear what "resolve the dict object" means.

Comment: Try and find a new project. LOL. You've got a pickle, for sure. This seems like a case for you to develop your own function that tears the tree branches down one by one and then acts upon them. It's JSON, so I don't know how much "speed" is actually going to be a factor.

Comment: @Pointy I don't know how better to phrase it. I want to "get" the object that contains the name/value pair `"name":"target"`. Forgive me, I'm a Pythonista talking about Javascript so I'm bound to get some of the lingo incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `link: 'tree.options[0].options[0]'` then `eval(path.to.link)`?

Following samples were tested with Chrome only. Same tree for all :

```
var tree = { level1: [{ key: 'value' }] };
```

---

### No `eval`

```
function resolve(root, link) {
    return (new Function('root', 'return root.' + link + ';'))(root);
}

var value = resolve(tree, path.to.link);
```

---

### Fallback to `window`

```
function resolve(root, link) {
    return (new Function(
        'root', 'return root.' + (link || root) + ';'
    ))(link ? root : window);
}

resolve(tree, 'level1[0].key'); // "value"
resolve('tree.level1[0].key'); // "value"
```

---

### Catching errors

The try/catch block prevents broken links from throwing errors.

```
function resolve(root, path) {
    try {
        return (new Function('root', 'return root.' + path + ';'))(root);
    } catch (e) {}
}

resolve(tree, 'level1[0].key'); // "value"
resolve(tree, 'level1[1].key'); // undefined
```

---

### Using custom path format

The good part here is that we can pass either an object or an array as `root`. Also note that we can replace the slash in `path.split('/')` with any char of our choice.

```
function resolve(root, path) {
    path = '["' + path.split('/').join('"]["') + '"]';
    return (new Function('root', 'return root' + path + ';'))(root);
}

resolve(tree.level1, '0/key'); // "value"
resolve(tree, 'level1/0/key'); // "value"
resolve(tree, 'level1/0'); // Object {key: "value"}
```

Comment: That's certainly interesting... Massively simplifies the coding side of things and security isn't really an issue here as I control the whole thing.

Comment: The without-`eval` version should definitely appease people who care enough but other than the arbitrary security risk with eval, what are the advantages of one method over the other?

Comment: Nothing in your case I think. I would say you have a better control on the origin of your path, for example you could pass copy of your tree to `resolve` : `resolve(treeCopy, path.to.link)`.

Comment: @downvoter I guess you downvoted for the dynamic code evaluation. Fear! Fear! Well, this is not necessarily the evil as long as you maintain control over the input : http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/.

Comment: Alternatives to dynamic code evaluation can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/1636522.