# Check JSON if has nested object

Tags: javascript, json

How can I check if `subproducts` object exists in my JSON?

```
"products":[
    {
    "id":5002,
    "description":"i dont know",
    "position":1,
    "weight":1,
    "subproducts":{
            "name":"test",
            "description":"description of test"
        }
    }
],
```

It keeps me returning true whenever I use `if(product.subproducts)` and `product.subproduct.name`, which cannot read name property undefined.

```
$.each(company.products, function (j, product) {
    if(product.hasOwnProperty('subproducts') {
       //do something        
    } else {
      // do this
    }
}
```

UPDATED: forgot to say that, for each products, contains subproducts or not.

Comment: what do you get when you log the output of ```typeof(products.subproducts);``` ?

Comment: it gives me undefined.

Comment: *"It keeps me returning true whenever I use `if(product.subproducts)` or `product.subproduct.name`, which cannot read name property undefined."* How can you get `true` if the code throws an error?

Comment: For the product.subproducts, returns true, the product.subproduct.name returns undefined.

Comment: if ```typeof(products.subproducts);``` is undefined, null or any type except an object, then you know it's not a nested object :)

Comment: soooo i learned it wrong.

Comment: You do realize that `product.subproducts` is not the same as `product.subproduct`? Accessing `product.subproduct.name` is very wrong.

Comment: You have an object that contains an array of objects. So `products.subproducts` isn't right, it should be `products[0].subproducts`

Comment: Lots of other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6927242/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/14782232/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/18381259/218196 . [Please use the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+nested+property+exists).

Comment: Please, I want to delete this question, because the error was misstype.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:

`products[0].hasOwnProperty('subproducts')`

Comment: You're right. Products is an array of objects. OP has to iterate to check every object for a subproduct key.

Comment: The OP is already doing that: `if(product.hasOwnProperty('subproducts') {`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you say subproducts doesn't exist, it does actually exist as an object, but with no properties. An object with no properties is still considered truthy in JavaScript, so that's why it always passes your truthy condition, and then throws the undefined error if you try to access the `name` property.

Example:

```
var obj = {};
console.log(obj ? true : false); // true
```

In this case you can test for the `name` existing:

```
$.each(company.products, function (j, product) {
    if(product.hasOwnProperty('subproducts') {
       if(product.subproducts.name){
           // it has subproducts AND the subproduct.name exists
       }     
    } else {
      // do this
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet would be to go through the object and check for an object:

```
function hasSubObject(products) {
    for(var key in products){
        if(!products.hasOwnProperty(key))continue;
        if(typeof products[key] === "object") return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which is gross and will probably slow down if you have large objects